# A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception - The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-programming, sspi

I have an WPF app, which uses SSLStream to connect to server and send/receive some messages. My code is largerly based on this example (SslTcpClient): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx.

This worked fine for months. However, after getting this windows update (Cumulative Update for Windows 10 version 1511 and Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 4: June 14, 2016 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3163018). My app started to report this exception:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
at MyAPP.Core.Services.Network.Impl.SslTcpClient.ClientSideHandshake()
at MyAPP.Core.Services.Network.Impl.SslTcpClient.Connect()
at MyAPP.Core.Services.Impl.MessageService.SendMessage(String message)
```

What can I do ?

Comment: We're having the same issue after this update on our Windows 10 machines. We're using the MySQL .NET Connector connecting to a remote MySQL DB over SSL.

Comment: Jon, have you found a solution ? I'm having the same problem with connecting to a MySQL DB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the solution, set in the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\Diffie-Hellman]
"ClientMinKeyBitLength"=dword:00000200
```

as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30479567/3925092)

Comment: [This link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3061518/ms15-055-vulnerability-in-schannel-could-allow-information-disclosure-may-12,-2015) is a reference to the MS Technical discussion for why DH 512 support was removed.

Answer (score 38):

This means the other side is using another version of TLS and you are using an older version.
Set up security attribute to TLS12 before making the connection.
This is a widely known problem, as many providers start using TLS12 (e.g. paypal,amazon and so on).

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: In my case the message is "No credentials are available in the security package", It also works, Life Saver!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SslStream, then you need to explicitly set the TLS version in the AuthenticateAsClient call, for example:

```
ssl.AuthenticateAsClient(url, null, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
```

Comment: i couldn't get this to work in any other way, so thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

I am getting a similar exception while connecting to the MySQL database hosted at Hostinger from a desktop app (.NET).

I have added `SslMode=None;` in the connection string and everything started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception when using `C#` connect to `Oracle` database using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`,

> "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Oracle Cannot connect to Server or cannot parse connection string ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x80004005): Oracle : Oracle Cannot connect to Server or cannot parse connection string  ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: **A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.** ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: **No credentials are available in the security package**\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, Byte[] message, Exception exception)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)\r\n   at  ............

and after a long time finding and try,  finally I find [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39979244/4573839) works, add `settings` section and set `name="SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES" value=""` in the `app.config`:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <version number="*">
    <dataSources>
      <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) "/>
    </dataSources>
    <settings>
      <setting name="SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES" value=""/>
    </settings>
  </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

In the reference link in answer above, you can try one step further, set:

> SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= ()

in your `sqlnet.ora` in `Oracle Client` folder also works.

Comment: This is not the same exception as the one in question, so your answer is irrelevant

Answer (score -1):

Adding line before your Web request.

```
const SslProtocols _Tls12 = (SslProtocols)0x00000C00;
const SecurityProtocolType Tls12 = (SecurityProtocolType)_Tls12;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12;
```

Answer (score -2):

try adding *servicePrincipalName* to your client App.config file

```
<client>
 <endpoint ............................
  <identity>
  <servicePrincipalName/>
  </identity>
 </endpoint>
</client>
```