# C# A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception - The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, exception, ssl

I wrote a C# program to connect MySql server with '[Mysql Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)'.
I use security connection with ssl option. I made the server certs and client pfx cert too properly.
But when I'm trying to connect to the server I get this exepction.

```
    System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
```

The MySql server version (5.5) is supported by the MySql Connector/Net version what I use (6.9).

*IMPORTANT: It worked in earlier Windows 10 but not in Windows 10 up-to-date.
My friend tested it in Windows 7 and 8.1  with success.
Maybe a Windows update messed up something.*

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925505/a-call-to-sspi-failed-see-inner-exception-the-local-security-authority-cannot) a solution: the registry must be edited, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, I think it is related to a latest security update of windows 10.
The error is gone when I change the connection string to turn of SSL encryption for my connection... 
EDIT: error is solved after updating mysql-server-5.5