# C# .Net 4.5 - System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException occurred in MySql.Data.dll On Windows 10

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ssl

I get this error after the new cumulative update of windows 10, there are no problems with Windows 7, 8 and 8.1, I hope you can help as I'm stuck.

I use a self signed certificate and MySQL requires that it should use SSL. I get the error when I connect to the MySQL database.

System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

```
if (MyConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
    MyConnection.Open()
}
```

My connection string is `Server=NameOfserver;Database=DBName;uid=User;password=Password;SslMode=Preferred`

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233087
Message=A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
Source=System
StackTrace:
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.StartSSL()
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
    at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Get_users() in C:\Users\al\Dropbox\Logbog 3.0 - Atlas\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 1456
    at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.load() in C:\Users\al\Dropbox\Logbog 3.0 - Atlas\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 219
    at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\alth01\Dropbox\Logbog Enterprise 3.0 - Atlas\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 167
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
InnerException: 
    ErrorCode=-2147467259
    HResult=-2147467259
    Message=Den lokale sikkerhedsmyndighed (LSA) kan ikke kontaktes
    NativeErrorCode=-2146893052
    InnerException:
```

Comment: Error is ["The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted"](http://www.errortoenglish.com/da/H7E5L4V2/Den-lokale-sikkerhedsmyndighed-(LSA)-kan-ikke-kontaktes.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception - The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031128/c-sharp-a-call-to-sspi-failed-see-inner-exception-the-local-security-authorit), also [A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception - The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925505/a-call-to-sspi-failed-see-inner-exception-the-local-security-authority-cannot)