# Error while creating connection in ADF to FTP

Tags: azure-data-factory, ftp-server

I am getting below error while creating linked service.

Failed to connect to FTP server. Please make sure the provided server information is correct, and try again.
A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
The message received was unexpected or badly formatted

Any idea how it to resolve this?

Comment: Provide your linked service configurations and error image for better understanding.

Comment: Previously, the connection was successful, and I could also connect to the server locally.

Here are the configurations I use, along with the port and credentials.
Enable SSL for secure transmission.
Enable Server Certificate Validation

Answer (score 0):

Here, the issue is related to SSPI. [SSPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Support_Provider_Interface) is a Windows component. It may be different according to OS versions. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72800116/ftp-download-file-generate-the-error-a-call-to-sspi-failed#:%7E:text=The%20error%20%22The%20message%20received,Downgrade%20the%20server%20certificate), the above error indicates that the server certificate uses an unsupported format (for instance, uses an unknown cipher) and thus cannot be processed by the SSPI layer. You can try the following solutions:

- Upgrade Windows
- Downgrade the server certificate
- Attempt to connect without using SSL

For more information, refer to this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-troubleshoot-ftp-sftp-http#error-code-ftpfailedtoconnecttoftpserver).

Answer (score 0):

Above error may come when below happens

- incorrect server information or firewall settings or SSL/TLS settings.

you can also try connecting FTP via different client, this will help determine if the issue is specific to azure data factory or general connectivity issue.