# "No credentials are available in the security package" when connection to Oracle is performed

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection, windows-10-desktop, oracle-manageddataaccess

The tests that performs connection to Oracle database started fail with AuthenticationException after last Windows update.
The message and stack trace are provided below:

```
    <ErrorInfo>
          <Message>Test method threw exception: 
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---&gt; Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: Oracle Communication: Failed to connect to server or failed to parse connect string ---&gt; OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException: Oracle Communication: Failed to connect to server or failed to parse connect string ---&gt; System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---&gt; System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No credentials are available in the security package</Message>
          <StackTrace> 
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, Byte[] message, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartReceiveBlob(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, ChannelBinding binding, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
   at OracleInternal.Network.Ano.StartNegotiation()
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.SendConnectPacketAndProcessResponse(AddressResolution addrRes)
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.ConnectViaCO(ConnectionOption connOption, AddressResolution addrRes)
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.Connect(String tnsDescriptor, Boolean doNAHandshake, String IName)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, String instanceName)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.&lt;Open&gt;b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.&lt;Open&gt;b__2()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass7.&lt;GetResults&gt;b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.&lt;System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable&lt;T&gt;.GetEnumerator&gt;b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.&lt;GetElementFunction&gt;b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Single[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
 </StackTrace>
        </ErrorInfo>
```

The exception is thrown when tests are run from VS Test Runner or from command line with mstest. 
The Oracle Database tools in Visual Studio throws the same exception.
In application the Oracle ManagedDataAccess provider is used. Package version is 12.1.2400.
OS: Windows 10 Pro x64
An application locally published to IIS works just fine. There are no any problems with database connection.
Does anybody know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same problem here. Today I reopened a console application started in august and Oracle gave me the same exception.
Solved switching back to version **12.1.22** of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess from NuGet.

**UPDATE 2016-12-27**

Found final solution here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3972810 
The problem is caused by SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES set to NLS.
To solve the problem you have to edit app.config / web.config:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <version number="*">
    <dataSources>
      <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) "/>
    </dataSources>
    <settings>
      <setting name="SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES" value=""/>
    </settings>
  </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

I added the `<settings>` section.

Comment: I have Oracle.ManagedDataAccess version 12.1.24 installed. The package update to version 12.1.24160719 didn't help and downgrade to version 12.1.22 didn't help either

Comment: Thanks! Adding a settings section helped.

Comment: It was easier to change "SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)" to "SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)" in file sqlnet.ora in Oracle client installation directory.