# Visual Studio 2017 - Data Connections - Add Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2017, odp.net

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (and Pro) (latest update 15.9.4) with Oracle Data Tools (ODT 18.3.0.0) installed. I am trying to connect to an Oracle DB (using ODP.NET Managed Driver) in the Data Connections under Server Explorer but it keeps throwing an Oracle Communication error. I have tried using TNS entry and EZ Connect. But no matter what I do, I cannot connect to the DB. To verify that I can connect to the DB from my machine, I used SQL Developer and was able to connect and see all the DB objects. I also was able to ping the DB using TNSPing.

Here is the error I get:

[Oracle Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr1Q0.png)

I tried to change the port number to see if VS can connect to the server at least and it seems that it can. It throws a ORA error as it should, so I suspect there is something else going on here when it tries to connect.

[ORA Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTk6t.png)

And I know that the DB can connect to VS 2017 since I am able to connect to it from another machine which has all the same tools installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So after trying this for hours with different options and banging my head against the wall, I finally found the issue.

Apparently this has something to do with the Windows 10 update that changes the way the managed client talks to the DB. For me to fix the issue, I updated my sqlnet.ora file as follows:
Change SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (**NTS**) to SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (**NONE**)

I can't take credit for this. While trying to figure out why even a console app won't work, I ran across this thread:  ["No credentials are available in the security package" when connection to Oracle is performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723323/no-credentials-are-available-in-the-security-package-when-connection-to-oracle/39979244) which lead me to https://community.oracle.com/thread/3972810.

If anyone else has a similar issue, hope this solves it for you!