# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No credentials are available in the security package

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> Database: Oracle
> Dotnet version :4.5

[image: Login error]

Comment: I'm afraid you get trouble to use ef core to connect oracle, could you pls check if [this sample](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/EFCoreSampleCode.html#GUID-71B4A0A3-7B88-4D4D-BC99-8ACB2F344280) helped you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No credentials are available in the security package" when connection to Oracle is performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723323/no-credentials-are-available-in-the-security-package-when-connection-to-oracle)