# After doing an update on VS 2017 I'm having an issue with net.mail (gmail) System.Net.Mail.SmtpException:

Tags: c#, wpf

After updating the application is no longer working, I tried a couple things which did not help 
ERROR:

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
Win32Exception: The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted`

Updating registry as mentioned here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/30479567/3925092

I also tried changing the ports which did not help. Here is the code that was working previously but is not after update

```cs
         var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
                Timeout = 20000
            };
```

Comment: `fromAddress.Address` are you sure that is a valid email address?

Comment: yes, it has been working fine for over a year, just after doing an update it stopped

Comment: Pls check this SO link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925505/a-call-to-sspi-failed-see-inner-exception-the-local-security-authority-cannot